# Adding a citation inside a citation with natbib including page number (secondary sources)

Tags: citing, multiple-citations

Currently, I am using this code:

```
\citep[as cited in \citealp{someotherguykey2013}]{someguykey2010}
```

but I get something like this:

```
(Someguy, 2010 cited in Someotherguy, 2013)
```

this coding does not show the page number. I want somethin like this:

```
(Someguy, 2010 cited in Someotherguy, 2013, p.3)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the keys of the entries with authors "Someguy" and "Someotherguy" are given by `x` and `y`, respectively, you could type either

```
(\citealp{x} cited in \citealt{y}, p.~3)
```

or, slightly more compactly,

```
\citep[cited in \citealt{y}, p.~3]{x}
```

For that matter, `(\citealp{x} cited in \citealt[\unskip, p.~3]{y})` produces the same output. However, I hope you will agree that this expression is nowhere nearly as succinct as either of the first two suggestions.

A full MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{x,author="Someguy",year=2010}
@misc{y,author="Someotherguy",year=2013}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={ }}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % choose a suitable bib style
\begin{document}
\citep[cited in \citealt{y}, p.~3]{x}

(\citealp{x} cited in \citealt{y}, p.~3)
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```